# Uploading a file using the Google Drive API v3 and php via html form

Tags: php, forms, google-drive-api

I'm working on a program that would allow users to select a file using a HTML form, and then the  program would upload said file to Google Drive and share it with a certain other user. I've been able to create a file in Google Drive and then share it; but once I tried *uploading* a file it all went downhill.

It's odd, because I think the code to upload the file is correct, so the issue must lie in how i get the file from the HTML form to the PHP file. My suspicion has sort of been confirmed by the fact that I attempt to echo $_FILES['myfile']['name'] nothing happens.

I'll upload two code snippets below, but I'll omit all the Google Drive api authentication for brevity's sake because that works.

#### index.php

```
      <form action="../Next.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <section class="file">
      <span>Please select the file to be uploaded </span>
      <br>
      <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
      <input type="file"  name="myfile" required  >
     </section>
    <section class="submission">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </section>
  </form>
```

#### Next.php

```
    $myfile=$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $type=mime_content_type($myfile);
    $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle('Test');
    $file->setDescription('Test');
    $file->setMimeType($type);
    $data = file_get_contents($myfile);
    $uploadedFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $type,
     ));
```

Please remember I have omitted the authentication code because I know that works.

I can't understand why this does nothing, from what I've been able to gather from looking around the internet the code is correct. I think the issue might have to do with the $_FILES['myfile'] array, and yet from all the documentation online it seems to be correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Inital Set-up

Due to your HTML file specification I assume your project structure is the following:

```
project/
├── templates/
│   └── index.html
└── Next.php
```

So I will start a php simple http server in the project folder using the command: `php -S localhost:8000`

### Approach

In order for this to work you will have to adapt your `Next.php` code a little bit. I recommend using the last Drive APi version (v3). There is no method `insert()` in v3 but it has `create()`.

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$myfile=$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => "Test",
));

try{

    $newFile = $service->files->create(
        $fileMetadata,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($myfile),
            'mimeType' => mime_content_type($myfile),
            'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        )
    );


} catch(Exception $e){

    echo 'An error ocurred : ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

### Reference

[Drive v3 REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference)

Answer (score 0):

if still not resolved then...
As you mentioned $_FILES is empty then i suggest to look at the file location in your project.
suppose your `index.php` is in `PROJECT->HOME->index.php` directory then your `Next.php` should be in `PROJECT->Next.php` directory.

Also you have to give submit a `name=submit`.

in `Next.php` test either form is set or not

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 print_r($_FILES['myfile']);
}`

And if file is not being uploaded let me know the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding multipart

```
$uploadedFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'data' => $data,
  'mimeType' => $type,
  'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to resolve the issue, I think the problem has to do with $data, as the $_FILES super global variable seems to empty for some reason; So I think the issue is that. If anyone knows why that would be of great help.  On the php.ini file_uploads is set to on and a temporary directory is set.

Comment: What does `print_r($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])` give?